# How to make a choose file action in Chonky.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, shared-libraries

I am using the Chonky library to create a file explorer for my app.

I need a way to select a file and retrieve its id on double click

```
            const [files, setFiles] = useState(() => [{ id: "1", name: "index.html" }]);

            <FileBrowser
              files={files}
              fileActions={fileActions}
              onFileAction={handleFileAction}
              clearSelectionOnOutsideClick={true}
              thumbnailGenerator={(file) => (file.url ? file.url : null)}
            >
              <FileToolbar />
              <FileSearch />
              <FileList />
            </FileBrowser>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it was relatively easy

What you need to do is :

Add this chonky action type to your fileActions array :

```
() => [
      ChonkyActions.ChangeSelection,
    ],
```

Then add a logical check in your handleFileAction function

```
if (action.id === ChonkyActions.ChangeSelection) {
  //Do something..
}
```